# Access Python class attributes from class methods

Tags: python, class, namespaces, scopes

As the following codes show, we can not access a class attribute from its method by directly using its name.

```py
class mc:
    m = 0
    def show(self):
        print(m)

a = mc()
a.show()
```

Using the usual scoping rule, `m` should be accessible by using name `m` in the method function. But it turns out that `m` can be accessed only by using `self.m` or `mc.m`. Is this rule inconsistent with the lexical scoping rule?
What is the rationale behind this design?

Comment: Use `def show(self): print(self.m)` instead. The idea is that `self.x` first looks into the instance for the attribute `x`, and when that fails, it looks into the class itself.

Comment: Summary of the answer: The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block. It does not extend to the code blocks of methods. Otherwise, it would make class inheritance confusing: e.g., a method inherited by a subclass would have access to the subclass scope too.

Comment: @jfaccioni  The idea that "`self.x` first looks into the instance for the attribute `x`, and when that fails, it looks into the class itself" is useful information, but is irrelevant to this question.